# How can I parse a comma separated string into two variables using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have the condition

```
var a = '2008, 1993';
```

I want to parse this string into

```
var b = 2008
var c = 1993
```

using javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var a = '2008, 1993';
var array = a.split(',');
var b = parseInt(array[0]);
var c = parseInt(array[1]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/X57KE/

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for **[split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** function like this:

```
var array = '2008, 1993'.split(',');
var b = parseInt(array[0]);
var c = parseInt(array[1]);
```

or like this:

```
var a = '2008, 1993'.split(', '), b = a.shift(), c=a.shift()
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`.split()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) lets you split up a string into an array of substrings based on a separator that you specify.

```
var a = "2008, 2009",
    items = a.split(/, ?/),
    b = +items[0],
    c = +items[1];
```

I would suggest a regex `/, ?/` to split on, i.e., a comma followed by an optional space - though if you know there will always be both a comma and a space you could say `a.split(", ")`.

Since you seem to want the individual items as numbers rather than strings I have shown how to convert them using the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29).